Foreign Key Constraint Error: Conflict with foreign key that doesn't exist
i tried to update my migration but then an error occurred

The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_ClassSessionsDetails_PeopleTypes_PeopleTypeId". The conflict occurred in database "cap_web", table "dbo.PeopleTypes", column 'Id'.

There seems to be no existing foreign key between ClassSessionsDetails and PeopleTypes, but I'm still getting this conflict error.
this is my migration code looks like:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace BlazorApp1.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class peopletypetocsd : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "PeopleTypeId",
                table: "ClassSessionsDetails",
                type: "int",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_ClassSessionsDetails_PeopleTypeId",
                table: "ClassSessionsDetails",
                column: "PeopleTypeId");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ClassSessionsDetails_PeopleTypes_PeopleTypeId",
                table: "ClassSessionsDetails",
                column: "PeopleTypeId",
                principalTable: "PeopleTypes",
                principalColumn: "Id");
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_ClassSessionsDetails_PeopleTypes_PeopleTypeId",
                table: "ClassSessionsDetails");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_ClassSessionsDetails_PeopleTypeId",
                table: "ClassSessionsDetails");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "PeopleTypeId",
                table: "ClassSessionsDetails");
        }
    }
}


does anyone know what might be missing here?

We'd better to refresh the data table in sql server management studio and the check the Foreign Key Relationships, to make sure whether the foreign key constraint existed or not.

I think you're running the migration against a database where that migration has already been applied. You can check this by inspecting the table __EFMigrationsHistory in your target database. If you have already applied the migration, it will be recorded in that table.

If you generated migration with EF, it should be OK.
Steps to investigate:

Is there already existing FK in database? If yes, remove it and try again. If not, proceed to next step.
You want to create non nullable FK, so when you add new FK column, it must be filled. Moreover, value inside the column must reference existing record in referenced table!!. This is harder to solve. I can suggest three approaches:

make FK field temporarily nullable (so introduce it as optional field with first migration), fill it appropriately, and generate another migration to make field not optional (non-nullable)
pick existing ID from referenced table and set it as default (in migration) for new FK column in referencing table, after it is correctly created, create new migration removing the default value
move all records from referencing table to some temp table, empty the table and apply migration - it will work, as there will be no rows, thus no FK conflicts, then reinsert rows from temporary table (adding new filled columns with references IDs, of course)



